# VBA: Format textboxes for all Forms

Tags: forms, vba

I used to use a module in one of my projects to format textboxes for all userforms in an excel workbook and the code was looking like:

```
Sub TxtBx(i As Integer)
    Dim uf As UserForm
        For Each uf In UserForms
            With uf("TextBox" & i)
                If .Text Like "" Then
                ......................................
```

Now I am moving my project to an application and I need the same module for formatting. So how to say in Windows Form Application like:

```
Module Module1
        Sub TxtBx(i As Integer)
            Dim f As  System.Windows.Forms.Form
            For Each f As System.Windows.Forms            
                With f("TextBox" & i)
                .....................
```

Comment: Which application are you moving your current VBA code to?

Comment: VB.Net But I solved it already. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Care enough to post the answer for the benefit of everyone in the community? :) You can mark it as the asnwer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't make it with .Net. I switched it to VB6 an it looks like :

```
Sub TxtBx(i As Integer)
    s.Language = "VBScript"
    For Each uf In Forms
        With uf("TextBox" & i)
            If .Text Like "" Or .Text Like "-" 
..................
```